# Xamarin.forms not triggering OnNotificationReceived() while app in background

Tags: firebase, xamarin.forms, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying firebase for the first time and want to save the push notifications the user receives into the app's cache.

```
public partial class AppShell : Xamarin.Forms.Shell
{
    private readonly ICachingService _cachingService = DependencyService.Get<ICachingService>();



    public AppShell()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        
        CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.OnNotificationReceived += Current_OnNotificationReceived;
        
    }

    private async void Current_OnNotificationReceived(object source, FirebasePushNotificationDataEventArgs e)
    {
        //does not work yet (throws exception) (look towards putting data is separate value)
        NotificationMessage notification = new NotificationMessage()
        {
            Data = e.Data
        };

        await _cachingService.AddOrUpdateNotificationMessageAsync(notification);
    }
}
```

this code works for notifications received while the app is in the foreground but it does not work while the app is in the background.

Comment: Have you googled? This is a topic that people have encountered many times over the years. Bottom line: while the app is in the background, *it is in the background*. That means it **is not** running your app code. (Well, you can run a background service, but that has restrictions, and is not usually how notifications are handled.) Read more about notifications. Personally, whenever my app re-enters the foreground, I ask my server for an update on any topics this user has asked to be notified about. I consider that more reliable than assuming no notification was lost while app was in background

Comment: you need to make sure your notification server sets the highest priority on the message itself - something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/64837000/1240083 
Otherwise it won't wake up the app if in background mode.

Comment: this is not working in MAUI for android.